# Invalid regular expression - Nothing to repeat - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get Video ID from entered youtube url with regular expression.

Below is the Regular expression I am using :

```
/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/
```

But It's coming back as

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `//^.*(youtu.be/|v/|u/w/|embed/|watch?v=|&v=|?v=)([^#&?]*).*//`: Nothing to repeat

Why?

Below is my code:

```
function PreviewVideo() {
var self = this;
this.links = $(".videoPreview");

this.bindEvents = function () {
    self.links.on("click", self.fireModal);
};
this.getYoutubeId = function (url) {

    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
        return match[2];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
this.fireModal = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var $this = $(this);
    var videoField = $this.data("video");
    var videoURL = $(videoField).val();

    if (videoURL === "") {
        $("body").append(UI.toast({level: "danger", time: 5000, html: "<h4>No video URL found</h4>", dismissable: true, position: "top-right"}));
    } else {
        var videoID = self.getYoutubeId(videoURL);
        if (videoID) {
            UI.modal({title: "Video preview", body: '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoID + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'})
        } else {
            $("body").append(UI.toast({level: "danger", time: 5000, html: "<h4>Invalid URL</h4>", dismissable: true, position: "top-right"}));
        }
    }
};

this.bindEvents();
```

}

Comment: the `/` after `youtube.be` is considered the end of the regex. You have to escape it.

Comment: @FabianKlötzl: It was escaped, the code just wasn't marked up properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please show your **actual code** creating the regular expression. Since you didn't use correct formatting when posting your question, we can't be sure that the above really is what you're using.

Comment: The expression in the error message looks different than the one you posted. Are you sure you are using that one? Is the expression contained in a string literal my any chance? It look like you are doing `new RegExp('/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/')`  (the double slashes in the error message and the missing escape characters are a strong indicator for that). That won't work. You should be using a regular expression literal instead: `/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/`.

Comment: Re formatting: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info, an entire toolbar of formatting aids, a **[?]** button giving formatting help, *and* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: This is the code snippet:

Comment: this.getYoutubeId = function (url) {

            var regExp = "/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/";
            var match = url.match(regExp);
            if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
                return match[2];
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };

Comment: @KrupaliChavda: See my previous comment. Remove the quotation marks. Use a *regex literal* not a string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions to learn more about regular expressions in JavaScript.

Comment: I did try that before Felix, but then it's error on "|" symbol, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token |"

Comment: @KrupaliChavda: Then you must have some other error. `/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^‌​#\&\?]*).*/;` is a valid regex literal. Maybe you forget to escape the first `/` ?

Comment: Escaping first character didn't make any difference, same error for |

Comment: Again, the expression you have posted is correct as it is. If it doesn't work for you then you need to post a *complete* example. We can only help you so much with the information you provide. See [mcve] for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the error message, the regular expression that is somehow produced by your code is not valid:

```
//^.*(youtu.be/|v/|u/w/|embed/|watch?v=|&v=|?v=)([^#&?]*).*//
```

The reason for this is that you put the whole regex literal inside a string:

```
var regExp = "/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^‌​#\&\?]*).*/";
```

This cannot work, partly because `\` is also the escape charter in string literals, so when you write `&v=|\?v=`, what is passed to the regex engine is `&v=|?v=` (and `|?` is not valid).

Simply use the regex literal:

```
var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^‌​#\&\?]*).*/;
```

Comment: changed my question

Comment: I copied the whole function into my browser's console and didn't get a syntax error. The code related to the regular expression is fine.